# How to replace a value in specific cell of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to make a python script which has a counter that replaces the current value of a specific cell in a CSV file.

My code is :

```
with open(ctlLst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csvReader.next()
    for row in csvReader:
        if row[6]>counter:
        newCTLcount=int(row[6])-counter
        #need to replace cell row[6]
```

The file looks like this:

```
 InterfaceCode  InterfaceSeqID  OperatorCode    CreationDateTime    MintransactionDateTime  MaxtransactionDateTime  NoOfRows    ControlFileName DataFileName
201 1170    30  20161005 04:30:27   20161004 06:55:56   20161005 03:08:37   8696    CTL_TripEventAndAlert_30_20161004.CSV   TripEventAndAlert_30_20161004.CSV
```

In this example I need to replace the value of 8696 (on row 2 cell 6) with a new value (newCTLcount).

Comment: What is your end goal? To have the changed table in memory or on disk?

Comment: on disc..this is just partial code...for just what i need

Comment: You should consider writing the data at the time your read it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's a good idea to write while reading/parsing to save memory

```
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
  with open(ctlLst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csvWriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvReader.next()
    for row in csvReader:
      row[6] = int(row[6]) # assumed as int
       if row[6] > counter:
         row[6] -= counter
      outfile.writerow(row)
```

For Python 2 see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

got it...

```
 rowData=[]
 with open(ctlLst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
 csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in csvReader:
        rowData.append(row)

 rowData[1][6]=int(rowData[1][6])-counter
 print ("new Row data count is " + str(rowData[1][6]))
```

thank's

Comment: How does this change anything on disk?

Comment: i think i misunderstood your meaning for disc...

this code saved the CSV file after changes on disc... that what i meant, you?

Comment: The above code opens a file in read mode, and makes changes to what it has read in. It does not write/save anything.